# How to display widget correctly when target cell is more than device grid size?

Tags: android, widget, android-jetpack-compose, glance

I'm developing a Widget and I want to make it's width cell size 5. (Android13)

So I create below code.

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...
    android:targetCellWidth="5"
    ...>
</appwidget-provider>
```

Most device I checked was OK.

But when App grid is set to 4(width)×4(height), the initial widget width size got 1.
(Setting -> Wallpaper&style -> App grid)

I think that happen when targetCellWidth is more than the number of app grid size(width).

But I have no idea what to do to fix it.
Actually I want to make my widget size as close as possible to the value set in targetCellWidth.
(ex: If targetCellWidth is 5 and the app grid is 4, I want the actual widget size to be 4 instead of 1.)

Can anyone know how to fix this?
Please help.

I set targetCellWidth to 4.
When app grid size is 3, the same problem happen.
When app grid size is 5, the widget size is as large as possible.